# Is it possible specify couchdb query parameters in a list based on current date?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchapp

I have a couple of documents in my couchdb formatted like this:

```
{ type: "event", start: "2012-02-08T19:30+01:00", title: "foo" }
```

There is a view that lists these documents using `start` as key. This is because these dates sort naturally:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type == "event") emit(doc.start, doc)
}
```

I can then access the next three events by ways of the `startkey` query parameter: `viewname?startkey=\"2012-02-08\"&limit=3`

Now I use a list to format this view with some HTML:

```
function (doc, req) {
  return provides("html", function() {
    // something with getRow() to query the view
  });
}
```

The current date is dynamic and cannot be specified directly in the map function of the view, but is there a way to set the `startkey` property in the list function? Before calling `getRow()` for the first time? Of course I could parse the key and compare it to the current date in the list, but that would invalidate the intentions of the query parameters altogether. Is there a better way?

---

**The backstory**

The list URL is actually rewritten from a much nicer URL. I have the following properties in rewrites.json:

```
{
    "from": "/ausstellungen/rueckblick",
    "to": "_list/rueckblick/exhibitions",
    "query": {
      "startkey": "\"2012-02-08\"",
    "descending": true
  }
}
```

The date is static, but the parameter should always reflect the current date.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. What I would do is: have a scheduled process that marks old events as... old, and emit only future events in the view.

Comment: Can't catch it. Why you can't provide current date to the view or list?

Comment: i guess, he is not using any 3rd layer like PHP, so the url-rewriting needs the actual date.. to work properly.

Comment: sorry, i could only update my comment the first 5 minutes.. so here again: i guess, he is not using any 3rd layer like PHP, so the url-rewriting needs the actual date.. to work properly. in this case, you would have to rewrite the design_doc with the url_rewrite handler and replace the startkey. This has to be done by a cronjob... or somewhere in the JavaScript-Code of the Site. 
Another idea you can look for: An update-Function that updates this design_doc every day and uses a date function internally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way to do this without simply discarding rows in your _list function based on reading `new Date` (which would cause caching trouble anyway) would be external to the database: either a smart reverse proxy or by making sure links to the view have the correct startkey. CouchDB's rewriting does not support JavaScript intervention, and anything past that level you will not be able to modify what data is fetched off of disk.